# how to allow empty String using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

Basically i have an email box where it only should contain characters are allowed in email boxes but can be empty, the problem is that when the box is empty then it pops my error which i have created saying

> Email box contain character that are not allowed

```
String UcharSet = "[a-zA-Z0-9-~!_#(@).]+";
boolean UMORN = UserName.matches(UcharSet);
if(!UMORN)
    PopMyError();
```

as long as i know i don't have the null character in my allowed list, so can you tell me how to allow the box can be empty too?

and do tell have i got all characters that are allowed in Emails.

Comment: Simple. Check for `null` / `empty` before you use `matches()`. Also, there is no `null` character in java Strings

Comment: Consider [`StringUtils.isBlank()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank(java.lang.CharSequence)) before matching by regex. It checks if input is null, or an empty string, or has only whitespaces

Comment: This is painful to read. Try to follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is to change the quantifier to `*`:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9-~!_#(@).]*"
                     ^ zero or more
```

You are currently using `+`, which requires one or more matches.

---

@TheLostMind has suggested that using `*` is inefficient, and you should check for null and empty input first, before using the regex to check for valid characters.

Whilst I agree that it would be more efficient to do so, I think that efficiency is a secondary reason here: if your intent in the code is to check the contents of the string *only if the user has entered it*, it is better to structure it in that way:

```
if (UserName != null && !UserName.isEmpty()) {  // Or use your favorite library.
  // The user has entered a value: check that it is valid.
  if (!UserName.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9-~!_#(@).]+")) {
    PopMyError();
  }
}
```

which is subtly different from saying that "an empty user name is valid", which is what is conveyed by the regex `"[a-zA-Z0-9-~!_#(@).]*"`.

(Of course, we can make this more efficient by precompiling the pattern to make a `Pattern` object, and then calling `pattern.matcher(UserName).matches()` in the condition).

Another advantage of pre-checking for empty/null strings is that you can reuse the same regular expression for validating in other parts of your code, where you *don't* want to allow such user names.

I'm guessing the above logic is to be used in some UI code, where the user is still entering the data; you might want to ensure that the username really is valid before you actually commit the data to the database, though. There, you'd *not* want to allow empty usernames; it is better to reuse as much logic as possible, to avoid inconsistencies: having the `+` form of the regex would be appropriate there.

Comment: I prefer not using `*` but instead checking using `null`, `isEmpty()` because using `*` will still create `Pattern` and `Matcher` which is not necessary

Comment: @jacky - No. Using `*` is valid. But not *efficient*

Comment: @TheLostMind true, I can see that; I would put that into the category of possible premature optimization, though. Y'know, the standard advice: only do it if you can demonstrate that is a performance bottleneck, and that changing it makes a meaningful difference.

Comment: guess you are right, figuring emptiness can give more ability to control the box exceptions

Comment: @TheLostMind on the other hand, I suppose it can more clearly convey the intent: "*if you've entered a username*, it must be non-empty and match this pattern", as opposed to "a valid username can be zero or more characters". But that's a much better reason for doing it than worrying about efficiency.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Not exactly *premature* IMO.  If this regex is being used a lot of times, then it could be a concern. Yes, premature optimizaton is bad, but *using good practices isn't* :P (Not saying that your answer is bad. In the current context, it is perfectly valid and correct)

Comment: do i have to i use `UserName != null && !UserName.isEmpty()` in my `if()` statement, i mean both checks for username emptiness right, i could just input `!Username.isEmpty()`, if not tell me the difference

Comment: You only need to check `UserName != null` if there is a way in which `UserName` can be null. Otherwise, it's a redundant check, as it will always be true.